# Tipping in hotels in Germany

Tags: germany, hotels, tipping, bavaria

When staying in a hotel in Germany (Bavaria), what are the customs concerning tipping hotel staff, in particular chambermaids?

- Is tipping expected, and if yes, how much?
- What is a reasonable amount for a long term stay?
- Is it better to tip daily, weekly, or just once?
- How to tip (to avoid an unintentional insult etc.)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Germany, service costs are always ([§ 107, 3.](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/gewo/__107.html)) included in the compensation. But it’s common to give a tip if you are happy with the service (but you are never required to). If you are unhappy with the service, you should give no tip at all (instead of a very low tip).

I found the following recommendations (sources are in German):

knigge.de, [Der Trinkgeld-Knigge](http://www.knigge.de/themen/gesellschaft/der-trinkgeld-knigge-6239.htm) ([here](http://www.knigge.de/archiv/artikel/der-trinkgeld-knigge-6317.htm) and [here](http://www.knigge.de/themen/gesellschaft/der-bezahl-knigge-7464.htm) also): for upscale hotels:

- room service: 2-5 € per delivery
- luggage carrier: 2 € per item
- concierge (for special services, e.g., organizing tickets for a sold out event): 10 €

spiegel.de, [Trinkgeld-Knigge: Man sollte, aber muss nicht](http://www.spiegel.de/reise/aktuell/trinkgeld-knigge-man-sollte-aber-muss-nicht-a-256574.html):

- *how much* to tip depends on how long you stay, hotel price range, and of course how much money you have
- it’s uncommon to round up the hotel bill at checkout
- always tip the luggage carrier and the room attendant
- you may leave the tip in your room (e.g., in the ashtray or on the nightstand); to make clear that it’s a tip (and that you didn’t forget your money there), you may leave a thank you note
- to make sure that the whole service staff gets a tip, you can give a summed up tip at the reception before checkout

experto.de, [Rainer Wälde: Trinkgeld geben - aber mit Stil](http://www.experto.de/b2c/rainer-waelde-trinkgeld-geben-aber-mit-stil.html):

- valet parking: 1-3 €
- porter (for calling a taxi; for helping to get into the taxi): 1 €
- luggage carrier (often also the porter): 1 € per heavy item
- if you pay a restaurant/bar bill at the checkout, don’t forget to add a tip: 5-10%
- concierge (for special services, e.g., organizing tickets/presents): 1-3 €
- houskeeper: before checkout, leave a tip in the bathroom or at the nightstand
- houskeeper (for bringing additonal pillows, cosmetics, a vase, etc.): 1 €

berlin.de, [Trinkgeld](http://www.berlin.de/tourismus/infos/1758234-1721039-trinkgeld.html): tips for hotels in Berlin:

- luggage carrier: 1-2 € per item
- housekeeping: 2-3 € per day
- concierge (for special services): 5-10 €

faz.de, [Das „Danke“ gehört dazu](http://www.faz.net/aktuell/trinkgeld-das-danke-gehoert-dazu-1233135.html) :

- luggage carrier: 1 € per heavy item
- in general, you should say "thank you" when giving a tip (so don’t leave it on the table in the restaurant; don’t hand it over wordlessly); only for the housekeeping team it’s okay to leave it in your room (e.g., on the table or on the bed)
- tip valet parking service, porter, concierge/reception and housekeeping  separately

test.de, [So geben Sie im Urlaub richtig Trinkgeld](http://www.test.de/Trinkgeld-Die-Kunst-des-Gebens-1045934-1045963/)

- luggage carrier: 1 € per item
- housekeeping: 1-2 € per day (leave it on the nightstand)

Comment: Your answer is very comprehensive and helpful! One additional question: **How and how much to tip a receptionist?** I'm often staying in one particular hotel and one of the receptionists is very helpful and attentive, so I'd like to reward him in a decently (avoiding a faux pas) and appropriately.

Comment: @PetrPudlák: I have no experience with this. -- The mentioned concierges would be receptionists in luxurious hotels, I guess. According to the sources, you’d only give a concierge a tip for doing something special for you (1-3 €, 5-10 €, 10 €). Not sure if or how that would differ for receptionists, i.e., in normal hotels (I guess it’s rarer that they organize something special for you in the first place).

Answer (score 3):

You should, but you don't have to. Tipping is a reward for good service.

Answer (score 1):

[Tipping in Germany (whototip.net)](http://www.whototip.net/tipping-in-germany):

> **Tipping etiquette for hotels in Germany**
>
> *Tip good service at hotels.*
>
> In Germany tipping is expected in hotels. If you receive good service you should tip your porter 1-3 Euros per bag and your housekeeper 3-5 Euros per night (you can leave the tip on the bed or nightstand). If your concierge provides good service, you can tip up to 10-20 Euros.

Hope this helps

Comment: Based on looking up several other countries on that site, I'm not sure that I would put too much weight in it's answer.  At best, it's on the *very* high end of normal.

Comment: Does this apply to all hotels or just "star" hotels? I've only ever stayed at the cheapest hotel in town in Germany and Europe generally. I think I paid 50 euro, maybe less in Regensburg, Bavaria. Should I have tipped there?

Answer (score 1):

I think tipping for normal paid work is a bad habit to support and is not expected or traditional in Germany. I never leave tips other than (generously) rounding off. And none to housekeepers etc