# Do hotel cleaning personnel have any benefit from leaving empty bottles in the room as opposed to returning them to the store?

Tags: germany, etiquette, tipping

In some countries a way of tipping the cleaning personnel is to leave a small amount of money (e.g. [In Portugal about €1](https://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g189100-s606/Portugal:Tipping.And.Etiquette.html)).

While in Germany, I have noticed the well known pro-recycling policy that costs a significant amount of extra money when buying some water or juice bottles (but that is payed back when returning the bottle). The most convenient way is to leave these empty bottles in the room and I was wondering if the cleaning personnel can have a benefit from this, so this may also count as tipping.

**Question:** Do hotel cleaning personnel accrue any benefit from leaving empty bottles in the room, as opposed to the purchaser returning them to the store?

Comment: The deposit for returnable plastic bottles and drinks cans might be called significant (25 cents), but note that for glass bottles it's only 8 cents; probably, few people will thank you for leaving a 96-cent tip in the form of 4 kilos of dirty glass :).

Comment: For some additional context, returning an entire [large IKEA bag](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/17228340/) filled with empty bottles to the point of almost overflowing typically gets me about 3 euros (plus a tired shoulder).

Comment: I once knew some American cleaning staff who would collect cans and bottles and take them home to claim the deposit (whether or not they had the official approval of their employers, I cannot say), but this was very clearly just a side source of income and not a tip. Given [the amount of a tip you might leave for housekeeping in Germany](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21570/tipping-in-hotels-in-germany), it's hard to imagine leaving 8+ plastic bottles out every night.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the personnel doesn't know if a guest will take empty bottles with him at the end of his stay, simply removing empty bottles from the room can be considered theft.
I guess, in Portugal (or anywhere else on earth), the personnel will also not remove money found somewhere in the room; the code is to place the tip clearly visible on the pillow.
But how to clearly indicate an empty bottle as tip? Put it into the trashbin? Together with banana peels and other junk?
As long as there is no code for this type of tip, personnel would only remove bottles at the end of the stay.

Next, the guest makes the personnel do extra work to get the tip. Someone has to collect all bottles (paid working hours) and bring them to the next supermarket (for sure not paid). One bottle is 0.25€, minimum wage is ~9€, so one hour is 36 bottles minimum. Collectig bottles over a longer time might help against the last point, but supermarkets are not very pleased if someone comes to bring 300 bottles.

And finally, empty bottles are some kind of waste. Leaving waste is a weird kind of tip, even if its value is significant...

Maybe a few words about this deposit system:

- There are the traditional returnable bottles. They are made of glass or of thick PET (one can not squeeze them), are collected in boxes (one might even buy a box of bottles), and will be refilled. Those boxes make them easy to handle from the producer to the shop, the customer and back to the shop and the producer. So, this bottles/boxes are preferred by restaurants, hotels and other gastronomy. The deposit on those bottles ranges from 0.08 to 0.15€.
  Due to the low value, and since the bottles will just end up in the same boxes as the bottles from the hotel gastronomy, leaving such bottles in the roomis not a tip.
- In 2003, a deposit of 0.25€ was introduced by law on all light PET bottles (one can squeeze them) and cans which contain sparkling drinks. (Yes, no mandatory deposit on the same kind of bottle, if it contains juice). The bottles are recycled, not reused. Therefore, most supermarkets today have machines where inserted bottles are crushed up to save space, and the customer gets a voucher to get the money back. The machines also count the bottles for accounting with the next stage in the return chain. The customer, however, should not crush the bottles, since the machine will not recognize them. So, one has a big pile of bottles, and has to keep then as they are, just for the machine to recognize and crush them... Since heat and cold in the car tend to squeeze the bottles, one often has to lift the lid of some bottles to bring them back in shape in front of the machine.
  You see, this bottles are quite annoying, and this is why gastronomy avoids them. For the same reason, the entire handling might make them a loss as tip, despite the high value.

Comment: Your first sentence seems to assume the bottles were bought on the premises.  The question implies almost the opposite "returning them to the store" in which case they never belonged to the hotel or its staff but to the OP.

Comment: *supermarkets are not very pleased if someone comes to bring 300 bottles*, are you sure?

Comment: +1 to gerrit's comment.  It's less time-cost to deal with one person than many, so fewer, larger deposit return transactions would be preferred.  The primary exception would be when reaching the limits of the deposit-returner's storage capacity.

Comment: @gerrit Some actually even have signs saying that they only accept bottles in quantities expected from a normal household, so I'd say yes, at least some are not very pleased. This can also very often be seen due to the level of maintenance which the recycling machines see.

Comment: Most supermarkets in Denmark have machines where you put the bottles in one at a time and it then does scanning/imaging/... to determine the value and whether it should be crushed (as described), and then prints out a receipt you can take into the store and either get your money (possibly as a discount on your purchase) - it's probably the same in many other countries in Europe (in some it might only be "some" and not "most") - in that case the supermarket won't care much, but you'll spend a lot of time and annoy others that would like to return bottles.

Comment: "how to clearly indicate an empty bottle as tip" - putting it *next to* (or on top of) the rubbish bin should be a fairly clear indicator that they can take it in my experience, at which point they can decide what to do with it (which may include just dumping it in the trash or regular recycling). I would agree one shouldn't really think of it as a tip though.

Comment: I've seen supermarkets where one could return an entire crate of bottles at the same time (24 bottles), to have twelve such crates after a big party is a lot but not exceptional.  Are such crate returns uncommon?

Comment: @gerrit I’ve lived in Germany since 2010 and I don’t think I’ve ever seen a bottle return machine without the crate thing.

Comment: The crate return thing is for things sold by the crate, like beer. Not for individual bigger bottles in random crates.

Comment: The thing is when one person is returning 300 bottles (which also likely were not all bought at this store), the bottle-returning machine will be blocked for several minutes while it eats the bottles one-by-one. During this time, other customers who just wanted to return their two bottles have to wait, and will become unhappy.

Comment: I often put bottles (especially ones which are to big for the bin) next to the bin and the next day, they are away. So I think they understand.

Answer (score 5):

> Does hotel cleaning personnel have any benefit from leaving empty bottles in the room as opposed to returning them to the store?

None at all, at least not officially. The bottles do not belong to the cleaning staff. Even if you put them in the trash bin, the contents of the trash bin *does not belong to the cleaning staff*. There have been court cases about people being fired because they took things their companies threw away. If the company throws it away, it must not be taken. The company wants it in the trash, it has to go in the trash.

Cleaning staff is not allowed to take *anything* from the room as their own, *not even the trash*. While specific hotels may have specific policies and exceptions to that, if you want to tip, then tip.

Comment: I wish we had the same in the USA. You leave an empty water bottle lying around and the cleaning staff snatch it up and thrown it away even if it is no where near the trash. Lost my tiny travel water bottle that way.

Comment: @Whitney This is one of many, many reasons I *never* let cleaning staff enter my room. I don't see much of a point.. I can keep it clean just fine, and I'd much rather not give anyone a chance to touch my stuff.